# Why isn't the boolean modifier working?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image]

When I use boolean on objects I've reshaped, it gets like this. If the object that has the modifier is a normal object that isn't changed, it just gets a hole in the top, like if the object is hollow. The other cube has a bevel modifier and doesn't really change at all, it just got some weird black lines. No problems when doing this with other unmodified objects instead of the number.

Comment: Welcome! For a better screenshot: *Main Menu Bar in Blender > Window > Save Screenshot*... And you can share the blend using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: please share the source file here (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), cause your question is not clear

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)